# Laravel 5.1 multiple variables in config::get

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Im trying to modify a file of my app in order to include also a name except from the email address that is included in the sent email, but i failed.

I can see two instances that are using config::get to parse the email.

I tried modifying them but with no luck.

Original code includes:

```
'from_email' => Config::get('database.email'),
```

and

`->setFrom(Config::get('database.email'))`

I did these changes and they failed. Do I have any syntax wrongs there?

```
'from_email' => Config::get('database.email', 'My Name'),
```

and

```
->setFrom(Config::get('database.email', 'My Name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter to **Config::get()** is the default value that will be returned in case given value is not set in config file. In your case calling **Config::get('database.email', 'My Name')** will return the value of **database.email** or, if **database.email** is not set, it will return **My Name**.

It is possible that you just put the parenthesis incorrectly. If you do

```
->setFrom(Config::get('database.email'), 'My Name')
```

or

```
->setFrom([Config::get('database.email') => 'My Name']);
```

then it should work as you want it to. The second form allows you to provide a list of From addresses.

Comment: You probably mean

->setFrom(Config::get('database.email'), ('My Name')

but its not working either

Comment: No. Why would I mean ('My Name')? Both first and second parameter to setFrom should be strings.

Comment: Do you have "email" set in database.php config file? And why are you using "database" namespace to set the email? It's not related to the database

Comment: because 'emai' is stored as a variable in database.php file. It works fine with this command ->setFrom(Config::get('database.email')) - but this way there is only an email address in the "FROM" field, not a name

Comment: I've updated the answer with another way of passing the email/name pair. Please make sure that Config::get('database.email') returns correct value, as second argument of setFrom is applied only if the first one is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set the default value to an email address.

```
'from_email' => Config::get('database.email', 'email@example.com'),
```

Comment: my purpose is to have a display name displayed in FROM of email. right now, only address is being displayed

Comment: That actually depends on the implementation, those attributes of which object.